# template 10 compiling error : 'PropertyChanged_ViewModel' does not exist in the current context.

Tags: winrt-xaml, template10

i came from Microsoft course on edx, the template 10 is not working even after installing the NuGet Package, it gives me this error while compilling:

Error   CS0103  The name 'PropertyChanged_ViewModel' does not exist in the current context.

and with double clicking on it, it takes me to the DetailPage.g.cs and the error is in this function :

```
public void UpdateChildListeners_ViewModel(global::solarizer.ViewModels.DetailPageViewModel obj)
            {
                if (obj != cache_ViewModel)
                {
                    if (cache_ViewModel != null)
                    {
                        ((global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged)cache_ViewModel).PropertyChanged -= PropertyChanged_ViewModel;
                        cache_ViewModel = null;
                    }
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        cache_ViewModel = obj;
                        ((global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged)obj).PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged_ViewModel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i deleted those if blocks and the error disappeared and the app ran but without the Hamburger Menu, any idea on how to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

Please consider updating the Template 10 Visual Studio Extension to at least version 1.7 and the NuGet package to at least 1.1.2. Then, create your project using the Hamburger template and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have the same issue as the originator of this post. I have version 1.10 of T10 VS Extension installed. The NuGet package version is 1.1.3. So at the time of writing these are the latest versions.

Comment: I too have the same issue with the latest version of the VS Extension and NuGet package installed, when trying to build and run a newly created Hamburger template project...

Answer (score 0):

> takes me to the DetailPage.g.cs

Those .g.cs files are auto generated, and you shouldn't be modifying them. I think a clean build here would solve this issue, (especially after you've upgraded to a new version of T10)